# In VSCode how do I automatically go to next problem in my problem list after correcting an error with quick fix

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way in VSCode to after I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> and accept a correction with quick fix, to automatically run the key combo <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to move to the next problem without having to press it yourself?

I use a spelling extension and it to correct a word by selecting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> then selecting the correct suggestion. However after this selection I want it to automatically move to the next item in the problem list. Currently it doesn't do this but I have to Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> which is the default to open the next problem. Then I click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> again to select which correction applies.

I am not sure why VSCode doesn't have option to move automatically to the next problem after fixing the first. I looked at the settings and there isn't such an option.

Visual:

1. Have file with problems and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to navigate to first problem

   [image: screenshot showing Problem popup on a misspelled word]
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> and select a suggested correction from the list with mouse click or enter.

   [image: screenshot showing Quick Fix popup on the misspelled word]
3. After correction with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> the cursor stays on the corrected word and one has to manually click <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> again to to go to the next problem.

   [image: screenshot showing Problem popup still on the word after correction]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is such a feature. What I have done is to assign new keybindings for the two commands which are close to each other on the keyboard. So you still have to do it as two commands, but it is more seamless.